# Im trying to write to a file in a loop but it just seems to be writing nothing?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

Here is the full code, it is for a basic random alphabetical shift encryption. For some reason, the .write() don't seem to be working.

```
from random import randint
import time
import os
sentence = input('What do you want to encrypt? ').lower()
namefile = input('What do you want to call the encrypted file? ')
alphabet = {'a':0,'b':1,'c':2,'d':3,'e':4,'f':5,'g':6,'h':7,'i':8,'j':9,'k':10,'l':11,'m':12,'n':13,'o':14,'p':15,'q':16,'r':17,'s':18,'t':19,'u':20,'v':21,'w':22,'x':23,'y':24,'x':25,' ':26,'.':27}
alphabet1 = {0:'a',1:'b',2:'c',3:'d',4:'e',5:'f',6:'g',7:'h',8:'i',9:'j',10:'k',11:'l',12:'m',13:'n',14:'o',15:'p',16:'q',17:'r',18:'s',19:'t',20:'u',21:'v',22:'w',23:'x',24:'y',25:'x',26:' ',27:'.'}
shift = randint(1,27)
x = len(sentence)
y = 0
encrypted_file = open(namefile + '.txt', 'wt')
while y < x:
    letter = sentence[y]
    position = alphabet[letter]
    position = position + shift
    if position > 27:
        position = position - 27
    letter = alphabet1[position]
```

Here is the first .write(). This one is inside a loop.

```
    encrypted_file.write(letter)
    y = y + 1
```

This is the second .write(). This is a single use one

```
encrypted_file.write('\nEncryption Shift = ' + str(shift))
encrypted_file.close
time.sleep(2)
print('Done')
time.sleep(1)
print('Here is your encrypted file.')
time.sleep(2)
os.startfile('C:/Users/Jedidiah/Documents/' + namefile + '.txt')
```

Comment: Is the file written that directory/folder? Is there no error-checking available for a write? Do you get the print messages?

Comment: Is the file being created? If it is, it's possible that each write command is re-writing the file, and the last loop iteration writes "", leaving you with an empty file. I would check the documentation for write.

Comment: You are opening the file with:

    `open(namefile + '.txt', 'wt')`

I'm not sure what the 't' mode character does, the platform is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

The mode key "wt" doesn't exist.
check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)! for all proper mode keys

UPDATE: try this

```
from random import randint
import time
import os
sentence = input('What do you want to encrypt? ').lower()
namefile = input('What do you want to call the encrypted file? ')

alphabet = {'a':0,'b':1,'c':2,'d':3,'e':4,'f':5,'g':6,'h':7,'i':8,'j':9,'k':10,'l':11,'m':12,'n':13,'o':14,'p':15,'q':16,'r':17,'s':18,'t':19,'u':20,'v':21,'w':22,'x':23,'y':24,'x':25,' ':26,'.':27}

alphabet1 = {0:'a',1:'b',2:'c',3:'d',4:'e',5:'f',6:'g',7:'h',8:'i',9:'j',10:'k',11:'l',12:'m',13:'n',14:'o',15:'p',16:'q',17:'r',18:'s',19:'t',20:'u',21:'v',22:'w',23:'x',24:'y',25:'x',26:' ',27:'.'}

shift = randint(1,27)
x = len(sentence)
y = 0
encrypted_file = open(namefile + '.txt', 'a')

while y < x:
    letter = sentence[y]
    position = alphabet[letter]
    position = position + shift
    if position > 27:
        position = position - 27
    letter = alphabet1[position]

encrypted_file.write(letter)
y = y + 1

encrypted_file.write('\nEncryption Shift = ' + str(shift))

encrypted_file.close
time.sleep(2)
print('Done')
time.sleep(1)
print('Here is your encrypted file.')
time.sleep(2)
os.startfile('C:/Users/Jedidiah/Documents/' + namefile + '.txt')
```

if you want to overwrite the file use "w" for the mode key

Comment: BTW 'wt' is the key for a writable file. it works on all my other codes. I tried 'w' but I didn't write to the file either?